# Pregunta sobre python y la asignación de variables a un diccionario en un bucle

Tags: python-2.7

La pregunta es la siguiente:

Según la imagen que adjunto, me gustaría saber ¿por qué el condicional que he creado dentro del bucle en el segundo loop asigna None a la variable del diccionario? Debería hacerlo bien pero no encuentro la respuesta.

He intentado buscar en la [documentación de Python](https://docs.python.org/2.7/) pero no encuentro nada, si alguien puede aclararme esta duda se lo agradecería !!

Adjunto imagen:
[image: Imagen del bucle y su interacción con el diccionario]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que imprimes es el resultado de la iteración al comienzo, antes de setear la key "total". Si pones el print al final del loop veras que se setea correactamente. En la primera iteracion, la variable "i" no contiene "con" con lo que se crea la key pero se setea con None. Está mal planteado el loop porque en la primera iteracion seteas "neto" con el valor que deseas y "total" con None, pero en la segunda iteración, vas a setear "neto" con None y "total" con el valor que deseas. Puedes probar con algo como:

```
dict = {}
for i in cost_list:
   if "con" in i:
      dict["total"] = i.rsplit()[-1]
   if "neto" in i:
      dict["neto"] = i.rsplit()[-1]
print (dict)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Baurin Leza, lo que pretendía era quitarme esa construcción, para dejar el código más limpio. Me ha faltado darme cuenta de que estoy pisando las variables en cada loop. Muchas gracias por sacarme del error.